# How to sed or perl replace text with dots and slashes without quotation marks?

Tags: regex, awk, sed, command-line

I used following command and tried numerous varieties (including sed):

```
perl -pi -e s/multi on/172\.31\.1\.1\/32 dev eth0\\ndefault via 172\.31\.1\.1 dev eth0/g /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-eth0
```

error is: "Substitution pattern not terminated at -e line 1.
When i try sed instead, it complains about unterminated "s" command

Aim is to replace:

```
multi on
```

by:

```
172.31.1.1/32 dev eth0
default via 172.31.1.1 dev eth0
```

(without using any `| > " ' $` characters in the command)

Comment: The real question is *why* you can't use the characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to quote the command (why not?), you need to escape all the spaces.

```
perl -pi -e s/multi\ on/172.31.1.1\\/32\ dev\ eth0\\ndefault\ via\ 172.31.1.1\ dev\ eth0/ /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-eth0
```

OTOH, you don't need to escape `.` in the replacement string, it only has special meaning in regular expressions.

You also don't need the `g` modifier if `multi on` can only appear once on a line.

Comment: thanks alot for your answer, i tried it, thought it returned some errors (hope i did no mistake in pasting the command). Then i added it into shellcheck.net and it pointed me to the \/32 part where it suggested "This \/ will be a regular '/' in this context."
I turned it into \\/32 (adding one more backslash) and the "warning" disappeared and command worked! :) thank you for help.